# Making a PageReference absolute

Tags: force.com, pagereference

I have a controller that return `PageReferences`. This are all relative. 
But in some cases, I need to return back full URLs.

Something like: `http://www.google.com`

This works but, I want to be 100% sure how PageReference makes the decision to be relative or absolute.
How does it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [official doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_pagereference.htm) says that `PageReferences` could manage both partial an absolute without problem.

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('partialURL');
```

> Creates a PageReference to any page that is hosted on the Force.com
>   platform. For example, setting **'partialURL'** to **'/apex/HelloWorld'**
>   refers to the Visualforce page located at
>   `http://mySalesforceInstance/apex/HelloWorld`. Likewise, setting
>   'partialURL' to '/' + 'recordID' refers to the detail page for the
>   specified record.
>
> This syntax is less preferable for referencing other Visualforce pages
>   than `Page.existingPageName` because the `PageReference` is constructed at
>   runtime, rather than referenced at compile time. Runtime references
>   are not available to the referential integrity system. Consequently,
>   the platform doesn't recognize that this controller or controller
>   extension is dependent on the existence of the specified page and
>   won't issue an error message to prevent user deletion of the page.

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('fullURL');
```

Creates a PageReference for an external URL. For example:

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('http://www.google.com');
```

Finally, no matter how Apex manage PageReference. The Url will be analyzed and the browser will request it properly.